# How can I find the longest edge of a shipping box, as UPS does it, using if and else statements?

Tags: java

How can I find the longest edge of a shipping box, as UPS does it? Here's the code I have so far:

```
public class CheckPackage
{
    private int dim1, dim2, dim3;
    private double weight;
    private int temp = 0;

    public CheckPackage()
    {          
        setDimensions(0,0,0,0.0);
    }

    public void setDimensions(int a, int b, int c, double w)
    {
       dim1 = a;
       dim2 = b;
       dim3 = c;
       weight = w;
    }
```

I need to do this using if and else statements. The longest side has to be `dim1`.
I will be prompting the user for the dimensions and the weight.

Comment: Why 'else'? You don't need one.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by assuming the first number is the maximum, and then just check each subsequent number against the previous 'maximum'.  While I normally would create a 'maximum' variable at the start of the method, as you request this logic actually causes dim1 be the largest edge.

```
if (dim2 > dim1){
  dim1= dim2;
} 
if (dim3 > dim1){
  dim1= dim3;
}

return dim1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a>b){
            if(a>c){
                dim1=a //a is greatest
            }
            else{
                dim1=c //c is greatest
    }

    }
    else{
        if(b>c){
                dim1=b //b is greatest
        }
        else{
             dim1=c
          }        //c is greatest
    }
```

Comment: how do you do this when you prompt the user for the dimensions and want dim1 to hold the largest length?